# how to find the host name on the network given the ip address using go programming language

Tags: networking, go, ip

Using go programming language, I'm able to find the IP address given the host name, but what I'm looking for is to find the host name given the ip address. I tried researching the "net" package, but no luck.

Is this something possible in golang? please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LookupAddr](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#LookupAddr) should do what you are looking for:

> LookupAddr performs a reverse lookup for the given address, returning a list of names mapping to that address.